# Function with countable range

Tags: real-analysis

It is well known that if $f\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be continuous function that takes values in rational number then $f$ is a constant function.

My question:  let  $f\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function with values only in $\Bbb Q.$ What we can say about $f.$? My guess, there is no thing specific we can say. Any help will be appreciated greatly

Comment: Probably nothing. Maybe you should ask a more precise question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. Without further conditions you cannot say anything about your function $f$. The continuity assumption allows you to use the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ to deduce that is constant.